# Spock:Class Cast Exception but works with real call

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, spock

I am testing the following code when I test with spring boot start works fine ,but fails when I try to test with spock.And throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30 cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30 is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

How to resolve this issue.Updated the post with code and test where the test is failing

Test:

```
class JWTAuthenticationManagerSpec extends Specification {

    private JWTAuthenticationManager sut
    private Authentication authentication = Stub()
   
    def 'authenticate throws exception'() {

        given:
        authentication.getCredentials() == "Token"

        when:
        sut.authenticate(authentication)
        then:
        ForbiddenException ex = thrown()
    }
}
```

Class Method Testing

```
 override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication): Mono<Authentication> {
        //Unit Test Class Cast Exception is being thrown Here
        val token = authentication.credentials as String
        if (token.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            throw ForbiddenException("Invalid access token supplied.")
        } else {
            log.info { "JWT Token Validation Success"  }
        }
        return Mono.empty()
    }
```

Do we have to add additional coding in order to remove class cast exception thats been throwing here

Comment: Please edit your question and turn it into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I cannot compile and run a set of incoherent and incomplete code snippets and you don't even explain where the error occurs. Too much information is missing. Ideally, post the MCVE on GitHub as a Maven project. I cannot see Spring configuration, how you create your mock and many more details. Besides, what is `given: authentication.getCredentials() == "Token"` supposed to do? For stubbing mock methods, you want to use `>> "Token"` because `==` compares something, usually in a `then:` block.

Comment: Thanks using >> resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part

```java
given:
authentication.getCredentials() == "Token"
```

looks wrong. Comparing two values in a `given:` block will not help you, as far as I can see:

- If `authentication` is a mock, it will just return `null`, hence the comparison will yield `false` but not do anything meaningful.
- If `authentication` is a spy, it will return the original method result and the comparison result will depend on that.

I think you might have tried to stub the result of the method. For that purpose, you want to use `>>` as in

```java
given:
authentication.getCredentials() >> "Token"
```